# Logs when shutting down tomcat, what should I do with it?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

Iget the following when I shutdown tomcat 9.0.24. Should I do something about it or should I do nothing because tomcat is shutting down anyway?

> 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.145 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command
>   was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
>   13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.146 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler
>   ["https-jsse-nio2-8443"] 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.152 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"] 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.158 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service
>   [Catalina] 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.247 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [app] appears to have started a thread named
>   [Gax-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a
>   memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   java.base@11.0.4/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) 
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 13-Sep-2019
>   07:59:06.248 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [app] appears to have started a thread named
>   [grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very
>   likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native
>   Method) 
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:114)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:251)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:276)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 13-Sep-2019
>   07:59:06.250 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [app] appears to have started a thread named
>   [grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very
>   likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native
>   Method) 
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:114)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:251)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:276)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 13-Sep-2019
>   07:59:06.251 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [app] appears to have started a thread named
>   [grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very
>   likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native
>   Method) 
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:114)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:251)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:276)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 13-Sep-2019
>   07:59:06.252 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [app] appears to have started a thread named
>   [Gax-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a
>   memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   java.base@11.0.4/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) 
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 13-Sep-2019
>   07:59:06.253 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [app] appears to have started a thread named
>   [Gax-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a
>   memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   java.base@11.0.4/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) 
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 13-Sep-2019
>   07:59:06.254 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [app] appears to have started a thread named
>   [Gax-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a
>   memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   java.base@11.0.4/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) 
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 13-Sep-2019
>   07:59:06.255 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [app] appears to have started a thread named
>   [grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very
>   likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native
>   Method) 
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:114)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:251)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:276)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 13-Sep-2019
>   07:59:06.257 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [app] appears to have started a thread named
>   [grpc-shared-destroyer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very
>   likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   java.base@11.0.4/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) 
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 13-Sep-2019
>   07:59:06.258 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [app] appears to have started a thread named
>   [grpc-default-executor-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very
>   likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   java.base@11.0.4/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) 
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:462)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:361)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1053)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 13-Sep-2019
>   07:59:06.259 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@40a0364a])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.259 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@708ddfd3])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.259 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@2778f3d1])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.260 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@30a34f07])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.260 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@71702d3f])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.260 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@6f9d1785])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.261 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@5503e208])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.262 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@1d3aefd])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.268 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@3f46fb53])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.269 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@5e16e521])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.269 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@51a4472d])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.269 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@5930a229])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.269 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@6bd21eb7])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.270 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@204d101])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.270 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@716a6343])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. 13-Sep-2019 07:59:06.271 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@43aa9ccd]) and a
>   value of type
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap]
>   (value
>   [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@2d17b6ad])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to shutdown tomcat and re-start it without any issues, then I think it's safe to ignore the shutdown error logs, since in the end the process works as intended.
Worst case you can always do a force shutdown by using a kill -9 directly on the PID.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a leak on GRPC see https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/6692

I added this code on my GRPC server cleanup code which uses private APIs to clean up the left over threads after shutting down the GRPC server.

```
@SneakyThrows
@SuppressWarnings("java:S3011")
private void cleanGrpcSharedResources() {

    final Field instancesField = SharedResourceHolder.class.getDeclaredField("instances");
    instancesField.setAccessible(true);

    final Field holderField = SharedResourceHolder.class.getDeclaredField("holder");
    holderField.setAccessible(true);

    final Map<?, ?> instances = (Map<?, ?>) instancesField.get(holderField.get(null));
    while (!instances.isEmpty()) {
        instances.keySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> (SharedResourceHolder.Resource<Object>) entry)
            .forEach(resource -> {
                final Object instance = SharedResourceHolder.get(resource);
                SharedResourceHolder.release(resource, instance);
            });
        Thread.yield();
    }

}
```